com.huawei.agconnect.exception.AGCServerException: code: 5 message: url is null
What can be wrong with?
Failed to find provider info for com.huawei.hms.contentprovider
Error while getting app update info
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.huawei.agconnect.exception.AGCServerException:  code: 5 message: url is null
    at com.huawei.hmf.tasks.a.j.a(Unknown Source:17)
    at com.huawei.hmf.tasks.Tasks.await(Unknown Source:33)
    at com.huawei.agconnect.remoteconfig.internal.a$2.run(Unknown Source:8)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:644)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
Caused by: com.huawei.agconnect.exception.AGCServerException:  code: 5 message: url is null
    at com.huawei.agconnect.credential.obs.ac.a(Unknown Source:46)
    at com.huawei.agconnect.common.api.Backend.call(Unknown Source:17)
    at com.huawei.agconnect.credential.obs.ad.b(Unknown Source:310)
    at com.huawei.agconnect.common.api.BackendService.sendRequest(Unknown Source:0)
    at com.huawei.agconnect.remoteconfig.internal.a.c$1.onSuccess(Unknown Source:9)
    at com.huawei.agconnect.remoteconfig.internal.a.c$1.onSuccess(Unknown Source:2)
    at com.huawei.hmf.tasks.a.h$1.run(Unknown Source:27)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:959)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:232)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:317)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8705)

                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:580)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:886)
Couldn't get data from BaseResult, exception: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.huawei.agconnect.exception.AGCServerException:  code: 5 message: url is null

app module gradle deps:
implementation(libs.com.huawei.agconnect.core)
implementation(libs.com.huawei.agconnect.remoteconfig)
implementation(libs.com.huawei.hms.push)

build gradle root:
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url = uri("https://developer.huawei.com/repo/") }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath(libs.com.huawei.agconnect.agcp)
    }
}
...

settings gradle:
pluginManagement {
    includeBuild("build-logic")
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url = uri("https://developer.huawei.com/repo/") }
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url = uri("https://developer.huawei.com/repo/") }
    }
}
...

plugin agconnect was applied at app build gradle file:
apply("com.huawei.agconnect")

agconnect-services.json file was added to project folder at app module folder
Update
Ok. I have added the following to manifest:
    <meta-data
        android:name="push_kit_auto_init_enabled"
        android:value="true" />
</application>

But now there are the following errors:
HMSSDK_HmsMessageService: start to bind
HMSSDK_HmsMessageService: handle message start...
HMSSDK_HmsMessageService: onNewToken
HMSSDK_HmsMessageService: doOnNewToken:transactionId = null , internalCode = 907135000,subjectId:null,proxyType:null
HMSSDK_HmsMessageService: Apply token failed, subId: null
HMSSDK_HmsMessageService: onTokenError to host app.
HMSSDK_HmsMessageService: onTokenError to host app with bundle.
HMSSDK_HmsMessageService: start to destroy

class MessagingService : HmsMessageService() {

    override fun onNewToken(token: String) {
        super.onNewToken(token)
        logd("onNewToken $token")
    }
}


Adding classpath(libs.android.gradlePlugin) before agconnect plugin in root build.gradle.kts solved the issue:
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath(libs.android.gradlePlugin) // it's needed here for agconnect
        // in libs version catalog: android-gradlePlugin = { group = "com.android.tools.build", name = "gradle", version.ref = "gradleVersion" }
        classpath(libs.huawei.agconnect.agcp)
    }
}

plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.android.library) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrains.kotlin.android) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.google.dagger.hilt.android) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.androidx.navigation.safeargs) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.google.gms.google.services) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.google.firebase.crashlytics) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.google.devtools.ksp) apply false
}

and the following meta data as I mentioned before in the question:
<meta-data
    android:name="push_kit_auto_init_enabled"
    android:value="true" />

